# How to disable automatic image URL to image HTML conversion in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress at user content, if i paste image urls in editor, urls are immediately converted to the image!
What is to be done to disable this feature **URL to image HTML conversion** in the wordpress?

Comment: Having this problem for years, only thing that works is hitting ctrl+Z right after you  paste the url

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to output your image URL without converting it directly to an image? Try using the "Text" editor inside of Wordpress post (instead of "Visual" editor) and enter you image URL there. When you switch back to "Visual" editor you will see your image URL and not an image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> If I understand correctly, you want to output your image URL without
>   converting it directly to an image? Try using the "Text" editor inside
>   of Wordpress post (instead of "Visual" editor) and enter you image URL
>   there. When you switch back to "Visual" editor you will see your image
>   URL and not an image.

no! for example in demo qaengine theme https://qaengine.enginethemes.com/blog/question/test
if paste url image: https://cdn.enginethemes.com/qaengine/2015/01/128.jpg
to editor, url Immediately convert to the image!
i want disable and url paste Only displayed as text...

Comment: Yes it is what he answered  to you